# Retrieving XML from URL with authentication

Tags: php, html, xml, curl

I have been all over the internet trying to find a solution to my specific problem but no luck.

Basically I have a URL that I log into that looks similar to this:
https://some-website.university.edu.au:8781/elements/v4.9/users/

Which will return to the browsers an XML block of text with all of the users.

I am looking to use curl or SimpleXMLElement() or whatever it takes to bring that XML into my php variable and output it.

The closest I feel I have got is:

```
$username = 'usernameX';
$password = 'passwordX';
$URL = 'https://some-website.university.edu.au:8781/elements/v4.9/users/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

echo $result;
```

or

```
$url = 'https://usernameX:passwordX@some-website.university.edu.au:8781/elements/v4.9/users/';
echo $url."<br />";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
print_r($xml);
```

I'm not sure if either is close or whether curl is better than SimpleXMLElement() or if one or both just will never work.

I have added a screenshots to show the what is returned on the website. The login screen is just the browser default one. Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

[XML Returned on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/722dm.jpg)

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to do? Do either of these codes result in the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using curl imo:
You can try something like this for authentication with curl:

```
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'mypass';
$server = 'myserver.com';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
        )
    )
);
$data = file_get_contents("http://$server/", false, $context);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data);
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    print_r($xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to parse xml from remote url. *(not tested)*

```
<?php

$username = 'usernameX';
$password = 'passwordX';
$url = 'https://some-website.university.edu.au:8781/elements/v4.9/users/';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
        'header' => 'Accept: application/xml'
    )
));

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
```

**PHP**

- [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/de/function.stream-get-contents.php) — Reads remainder of a stream into a string
- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) — Reads entire file into a string
- [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) — Interprets a string of XML into an object

Comment: Thanks for the help but the above code doesn't seem to work. It will just hang there for a minute or so and then return nothing. No console errors either. I thought what I was trying to do was common and many people would have suggestions :S THanks

Comment: SOrry the php error log says: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://some-website.university.edu.au:8781/elements/v4.9/users/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /Users/me/Documents/index.php on line 15...Line 15 being:$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);